# Chrome browser window to show Person's name?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, tabs, window, rename

Google Chrome browser, Macbook Pro, OSX Yosemite v10.10

In Chrome, I use multiple "Persons" with multiple windows open for each Person.

In Chrome, when I click on "Window" and the open windows display in the drop-down menu, presently the name of the tab with the focus in each and every window, regardless of "Person" using that window, is displayed.

I would like both the name of the tab with the focus in the window AND the name of the "Person" using that window to display.

In the alternative, I would like to click on "People," select "Person A" then click on "Window" and see in the drop-down window a list of the Tabs that have the focus in ONLY those Windows being used by "Person A," rather than the current view of tabs with focus for ALL windows open by all Persons.

In the alternative, I would like to have the name of the "Person" using that window to display, rather than the name of the tab within the window that has the focus.

How can this be done?

Thanks!